# Is there anyhting Special Code need to written to replace An application

Tags: android

I have an apk file called HelloAndroid.apk.I got Insatlled it in my device.

After  Sometime when I used the same apk file to insatll without uninstalling the old one.
ie tried to replace the existing apllication.It Shows Apllication got not insatlled.

But after uninstalling the existing apllication and installing the apk file it got installed.

Is there anything special that i need to place in the Android Manifest file for replacing the application Or need to write any code in the oncreate,ondestroy etc method.

When i insatlled some another apllication like log collecter apk file that i have downloaded from the android market it got worked. So I think some code need to be done to replace the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you are not using the [same certificate](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) file to sign the apks. If you are only working with debug certificates you should note that every android sdk installation has its own debug certificate.

Comment: Each time when i create apk file I am Using the create new key  that's the reason for error.Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking. But I think you are asking this: why might I be unable to install a new version of an .apk over an old version?

And the answer to that is almost always inconsistent signing -- that is, the old one is signed with a different debug or release key than the new one. You can't replace one with a different signature for security reasons.

So, yes, you have to uninstall the old one first. That's normal and no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest file change the version number and then install on the previously installed app and it will replace the app.

check More on this here,
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html